# Disable indexing for Xcode projects selectively

Tags: xcode, indexing

Is it possible to selectively disable indexing for Xcode projects? The following question discusses how to disable it globally, but I would like to disable it for selected projects only.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959709/stopping-xcode-from-indexing

The reason I am trying to do this is because one of the Xcode projects, Chromium is too big and takes ages to index.

The similar feature is available in Visual Studio, but I couldn't find any in Xcode. I tried searching the Web, but to no avail.

Comment: Try this: Make an empty folder on Desktop & lock it (Get info > check locked) . Then in Xcode project, file menu > project settings. In derived data settings, choose custom path. Browse to select that locked folder and try if Xcode troubles you now.